# Will dwarves eat prepared meals before other foods?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

If I cook up some meals, will the dwarves eat those first? Is there a way to stop them from eating them (if, say, the upcoming caravan is excited about them?) entirely? Or would I have to forbid each meal as it was made?

Comment: You could always use the "food stockpile behind locked door" trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this page](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/40d:Food#Eating), "A dwarf with the "Eat" task will pick up a unit of food, often according to his or her dietary preferences, but also influenced by proximity and age of the item (new first)."  *Note that this article was written for an older version, but it doesn't seem that anything has changed in this regard.*

- If the meal is composed of foods lots of dwarves like, they are more likely to get eaten.  Not much you can do about this, since the preferences are randomized.
- If there is other fresh (or fresher) food nearby, the meals are less likely to get eaten.
- If the meals are stored far from the rest of your fortress (and good stuff is stored closer), the meals will be safer.

So, all that can *help*, but there are probably some more sure-fire ways to avoid the meals getting eaten.

- You could use burrows and prevent any dwarves from accessing a special stockpile with the meals.  The chef making them would still need access, of course.
- You could create locked doors with attached levers to "lock out" the stockpile area, which would require locking your chef in there for a while.

Whether any of this is actually easier than simply forbidding the meals, though...

Comment: Don't forget the reliable forbidden command. Just forbid all foods except the moldy old leftovers you want them to eat, and your hungry dwarf will eat that or nothing.  Edit: Oops, sorry, just noticed you already included that at the bottom of your answer.